# REST API Testing - Postman behaving as different client after each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise, postman

I am currently using Postman to test my REST API. I've built it using `Ruby-On-Rails`, and using `devise_token_auth` to manage users sessions. After a successful log in, my API is rendering a `client`, an `access-token`, a `token-type`(BEARER) and an `Uid`. These elements are needed for every request that requires the user to be logged in and have to be sent on the header.

Let's say I am creating an article using a POST. The first POST succeeds and creates the article but when I try to create another article, I get :

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Authorized users only."
  ]
}
```

I suspect either Postman is behaving as a different client after each request, or my API is creating an `access-token` for the user after each request.

Comment: How is the token added to your request in Postman?

Comment: I am adding it in the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the issue:

According to [devise_token_auth gem documentation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-token-management), the `access-token` changes each time the client queries the API. Thus, I had to update the `access-token`, on my headers, whenever I wanted to send a request to my API.

To prevent the `access-token` from being changed after each request, add the following line to `confing/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb`:

```
 config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer to this [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59096951/12096762) that applies to this question also. Using Tests and Pre-Requests scripts you can have Postman automatically save and update the token after each request.

This lets you use Postman without having to set `config.change_headers_on_each_request = false` inside your Rails app.