# How to configure Postman for requests with devise_auth_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

I need to document a RubyOnRails API with Postman but I don’t know how to set up the authorization for the requests that need token. I’m using [devise_token_auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-token-management)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use devise_token_auth the format of the cURL is the following:

```
curl -XGET -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'access-token: lW1c60hYkRwAinzUqgLfsQ' -H 'client: W_xCQuggzNOVeCnNZbjKFw' -H "uid: email@domain.com" http://domain/api/v1/auth/validate_token
```

So you need the next parameters to access: access-token, client, uid, url

To get them you need to follow these instructions:

- Create a new user with a POST request to your signup request, in this case is http://localhost:3000/auth and in **Body** with **RAW** format set the params you need to create a new user (like in the example) and click send.

[image]

- Now that you got the response of the request, the params you need are in the header of the request, click to **Headers** tab to see them.

[image]

- Then create a new request in Postman with the GET that requires the authorization and in **Headers** set the values **access-token**, **client**, **uid** from the header of the last request.

[image]

You could set the values as local variables in an [environment](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments) to call them in every request instead of pasting them in each header.

In case you got an Authorization error after complete this guide

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Authorized users only."
  ]
}
```

This is because sometimes the access-token is configured to change each time the client queries the API, to change this configuration only add the following line to
config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb

```
config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
```

[REST API Testing - Postman behaving as different client after each request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007544/rest-api-testing-postman-behaving-as-different-client-after-each-request?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Having to set `config.change_headers_on_each_request = false` may not be ideal for everyone.

I was able to have Postman automatically save access-token, client, and uid to environment variables (in my case I used ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_CLIENT, and ACCESS_UID) with a Postman test script:

```
responseHeaders['access-token'] && pm.environment.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", responseHeaders['access-token']);
responseHeaders['client'] && pm.environment.set("ACCESS_CLIENT", responseHeaders['client']);
responseHeaders['uid'] && pm.environment.set("ACCESS_UID", responseHeaders['uid']);
```

This script first tests to make sure the token was returned (in a failed request a new token is not returned), then saves them to your environment variables.

Then using a Pre Request script I have those variables added to the header automatically.

```
pm.request.headers.upsert({key: 'access-token', value: pm.variables.get("ACCESS_TOKEN") });
pm.request.headers.upsert({key: 'client', value: pm.variables.get("ACCESS_CLIENT") });
pm.request.headers.upsert({key: 'uid', value: pm.variables.get("ACCESS_UID") });
```

I add these at the Collection instead of each specific request in Postman:

[Collection Edit screen, Pre-request Scripts tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLVpH.png)

[Collection Edit screen, Tests tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aCQS.png)

Then all I need to do before I start making requests, is to make a Login request to get the initial token (which will get saved thanks to our Test script). Each successful request after that will automatically save and use the newest token, allowing you to test your API without having to modify the config settings inside your Rails app.

Hope this can help anyone who finds this question.

Comment: Had to use `collectionVariables` instead of `environment` or `variables` but worked really well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you are using devise_auth_gem, you have to set uid which can be your email and when you log in with correct credentials, you will get a response in which client, access_token and uid along with other data were there which are saved in the database. So if you request for and new action of a controller which requires logged_in user you have to pass those client, access_token and uid from headers which matches from db and then you are authorised to use that method. If the request is successful you will get a response in which new access_token were there. So if you have to call another action you have to pass new access_token along with client and uid each time. And Client is same for one login. If you re login you will get another client.